# Why do I get a Signature Parse Error when Optional 'orElseThrow()' method called

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, glassfish, option-type

Why do I get the following exception?

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError: Signature Parse error: 
>   Expected Field Type Signature
>     Remaining input: +Ljava/lang/AssertionError;

when using the `orElseThrow` method for an `Optional` result:

```
public void removeFP(String port, String flight) {
    FPDto fp = findFP(port, flight).orElseThrow(() -> new AssertionError("..."));

    flightplans.remove(fp);
}
```

I'm deploying to Glassfish v 4.1 on JDK 8_u25. Eclipse Kepler SR2 with Java 8 support doesn't show any syntax errors.

Comment: Can you please post your stack-trace ?

Comment: This looks correct, pls share more information